# What device to select for bootloader installation in Ubuntu 20.04 while dual booting?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows, 20.04

So, I have my Windows 10 installed on my 128 GB SSD and the rest of my files stay in my HDD (1 TB) because there isn't much space left on the SSD (around 20 GB). I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 through the "Something else" pathway on the free space of my HDD (I have around 150 GB free space there for it).

My PC runs a **UEFI**. My **efi** system partition is present **on my SSD**.

I am clear with all the other selections in the installation process like creating the root and swap partitions (which I want to create only on my HDD).

*I want to know what will be the best selection for "Device for Bootloader installation".* What Should I select from the following? -

1. The **efi partition** on my SSD
2. My **complete SSD**
3. My **complete HDD**
4. My **"/" partition**

If I am not wrong my UEFI won't allow me to take help of EasyBCD to dual boot from Windows Bootloader. GRUB will be my only simple option, right?

Also, if possible, explain what will be the consequences of selecting either of these options?

**PS**: Well, I know this is going to be a partially repeated question. But older posts which answer the similar question are either for older versions of Ubuntu or Windows or simply don't cover the installation when Windows is installed in a separate SSD. I want to create an updated and compact question.

Comment: if selecting the *complete ssd* device (not the partition) is available choose that instead of the efi partition. ubuntu would figure out installation to the efi by itself

Comment: @ptetteh227 Thanks. In this case would if replace my older efi partition files or both the new and old ones get be kept in the same efi partition?

Comment: ubuntu would preserve the windows efi files

Comment: Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer in UEFI mode ignores any selection you make and installs grub to first drive's ESP. I do like to have an ESP on sdb drive, but use it more for backup of ESP which most users do not backup but should. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379